# Swagger UI into dropwizard

Tags: swagger-ui, dropwizard

I added folder dist from swagger-ui github and provide path to openapi.yaml in index.html

`url: "/openapi/openapi.yaml"`

Now I can see UI by the address http://localhost:63342/dropwizard-example/com/example/dropwizard/dist/index.html or access by the file index.html

How I can provide UI by my path?
Something like: dropwizard-project-work.com:8080/dist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe for someone will be useful.
Move dist folder from swagger-ui to resources.

In folder dist find index.html and change option url to your path of openapi specification file

Add dropwizard-assets dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-assets</artifactId>
            <version>{dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

In initialize method add Bundle

```
    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<BasicConfiguration> bootstrap) {
            bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/resoursePath", "/uriPath", "index.html"));
    }
```

Now swagger UI available at localhost:{your port}/{applicationContextPath}/uriPath